# Printing individual components of comment-form in comment-wrapper.tpl

Tags: comments, forms

In my comment-wrapper.tpl.php I was doing

```
print render($content['comment_form']);
```

which worked fine. But to render  the comment-form according to given theme, I tried doing this:

```
<div id="comments" class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>

   print render($content['comment_form']['author']);  
   print render($content['comment_form']['field_email']);
   print render($content['comment_form']['comment_body']);
   print render($content['comment_form']['actions'['submit']);
   print drupal_render_children($form); 


 if ($content['comments'] && $node->type != 'forum'):
     print render($title_prefix);
    <h2 class="title"><?php print t('Comments'); ?></h2>
     print render($title_suffix);
endif;
```

This code is printing all the components of the form  but the submit button is not working as it should. When I click the submit button it is not giving any reaction. Do I need to add any more lines of code to make this comment form work  ? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to render hidden form fields that are required for the correct work.

Just add this line of code after outputting all visible form fields:

```
<?php 
  print drupal_render_children($form); 
?>
```

Also if you output form elements outside form template you need manually add {form} tag
In your case you will get

```
<form id="comment-form" class="comment-form" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" action="<?php print url('node/' . $node->nid); ?>#comments">
<?php
  print render($content['comment_form']['author']);  
  print render($content['comment_form']['field_email']);
  print render($content['comment_form']['comment_body']);
  print render($content['comment_form']['actions']['submit']);
  print render($content['comment_form']['actions']['preview']);
  print drupal_render_children($content['comment_form']); 
?>
</form>
```

Comment: I tried that, it didnot work.

Comment: Please provide full code of your comment-wrapper.tpl.php

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: I edited answer.

Comment: I tried this code. Still the button is not working as it should. The click on the button is not showing any reaction.

Comment: Answer is updated